# Windows IDE for Python

Tags: windows, python, ide

I am a beginner in Python and in search of an IDE.

My requirements:

- a) Support to build libraries as in you have a project folder and can keep adding files, e.g.: Visual Studio, Eclipse.
- b) Can add a library (I don't if any libraries are available but can be added if available) to convert Python code into C.

Optional: Can add a library to build GUI applications.

I have come across the question [*What IDE to use for Python?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python) while surfing Stack Overflow. It's a beautiful link as in it talks about lot of regular features (auto completion, code folding etc.) of the IDE. However, it doesn't answer my above questions.

I am using windows 10, RAM 4 GB and have 100 GB of disk space allocated for Python.

Comment: I am pretty sure any Python IDE satisfies these requirements.

Comment: @Nicolas: Ok, Now I am deviating slightly off topic. Can Cython be integrated into these IDE's (PTVS, PyDev, NetBeans). Atleast, on the pydev.org nothing is mentioned about cython

Comment: The stack overflow answer you linked seems pretty comprehensive. Several of the software mentioned there do meet your first requirement if I understood it correctly. E.g. Spyder has a [project explorer plugin](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/projectexplorer.html). As for the second point, python translation is independent of the IDE. For that I suggest you check the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7112812/1836949)

Comment: @Timmy: I have gone through your suggested post. PyPy Interpreter and PyPy tool chain both are mentioned. What should I download, the download button takes me to PyPy2.7v5.31? Is this an IDE? What about the tool chain, is that a separate entity or comes along with PyPyv5.31? There is no answer on this on the PyPy website.

Comment: PyPy is an alternative implementation of Python, which has libraries for translating your programs to C. However, before getting it, please take some time to familiarize yourself with the standard Python and its different implementations. v2.7 and v3.5 are the newest versions of Python2 and 3 respectively. Choose the one which better suits your application.

Comment: @Timmy: Looks like going over with Cython is a better choice compared to PyPy after going through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946662/why-shouldnt-i-use-pypy-over-cpython-if-pypy-is-6-3-times-faster)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For python development, I am a huge fan of Jetbrains products so their offering, [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/), is what I am going to suggest.  There is a free version of the IDE which does let you keep adding files (no restrictions on project sizes as far as I know), and there are plugins which can be added; which would mean if there is one for converting Python into C, you'd be able to add it to your editor.

It has type hinting support for Python 2 and 3, code folding, version control integration and lots of other features.